# Asymptotic notation - algorithm to find n_0 and c constants for two functions

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I´m creating asympnotic notation calculator for my bachelor thesis.

So I have two function  **f, g** (polynomial for example) and I need find **n_0** and **c** constants for which **f(n)<=c.g(n)** or **f(n)=>c.g(n)** depends on which functions will grow faster.

How should I proceed?

Comment: You are not guaranteed that such constants exist for every choice of f,g. In fact you know sometimes there are no such consonants. e.g. `f(x)=0 ; g(x)=sin(x)`. If you restrict f,g to be polynomials then you can look at their respective highest powers' coefficients and deduce which is the growing faster and continue from there.

Comment: Is the question limited to polynomials, or not? If not, what is the class of functions that are under consideration? Note that in general it is quite easy to write down functions which are extremely difficult to analyse (for example: ackermann's function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you have to solve equation

```
f(x) - y * g(x) = 0
```

Note that you have two variables for single equation, so it impossible to find both unknowns together (except for special equation kinds)

So you have to fix either "constant" factor or n value and solve equation with one unknown (if possible)

Example:

```
f(n) = n^2 + n
g(n) = 2*n + 5
fix c = 2
f(n)-2*g(n) = n^2 + n - 4*n - 10 =  
              n^2 - 3*n - 10 = 0
```

valid root for n is   **n0 = 5**  (there parabola and straight line intersect)

Comment: This is quite clear to me, but how to find one of these variables?

Comment: How you determited that c = 2?

Comment: As I said,  it is impossible to determine **both** unknowns parameters. So I gave arbitrary value to C. Note that asymptotic notation usually omits constant multiplier, and comparing concrete function values is not correct way. We can only say that quadratic function is larger than linear one "after some value of n"

Comment: Although c has arbitrary value there have to be some rules to assign value to c... otherwise it wouldn´t be in task :(